# libvirt cannot start qemu-system-x86_64 for Unknown Error on m1 mac

Tags: macos, virtual-machine, qemu, apple-m1, libvirt

This is the error I got from running `virsh define ubuntu.xml` on a m1 mac.

```
error: Failed to define domain from ubuntu.xml
error: internal error: Failed to start QEMU binary /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 for probing: qemu-system-x86_64: Unknown Error
```

I tried to run `virsh capabilities` but it just hangs. However, if I start libvirt with sudo, I am able to get results from `virsh capabilities` which contains support for other qemu binaries except for `qemu-system-x86_64`.

I also tried to switch to using `qemu-system-i386` and change arch to `i686`, then I am able to define the vm with no error. But what should I do to make libvirt to work with `qemu-system-x86_64`?

I also checked that I am able to run `qemu-system-x86_64` on the terminal.

Here is my minimal xml file:

```
<domain type='qemu' xmlns:qemu='http://libvirt.org/schemas/domain/qemu/1.0'>
    <name>ubuntu</name>
    <uuid>c7a5fd1d-cdaa-8125-762c-c12d39ab8362</uuid>
    <memory unit='GB'>2</memory>
    <currentMemory unit='GB'>2</currentMemory>
    <vcpu>2</vcpu>
    <os>
        <type arch='x86_64' machine='q35'>hvm</type>
        <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    </os>
    <devices>
        <emulator>/usr/local/bin/qemu-system-x86_64</emulator>
        <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
            <source file='<path to iso>'/>
            <target dev='hdc'/>
            <readonly/>
        </disk>
        <disk type='file' device='disk'>
            <source file='<path to img>'/>
            <target dev='hda'/>
        </disk>
    </devices>
</domain>
```

Comment: Does anyone have the same issue?